# How to make ScrollTo scroll to the same y

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a TextView that contains a big text and a ScrollView.
So I wanna make a Table of contents for it.
But using the smooth/scrollTo it gives different results on different devices.
I'm trying to achieve scrolling to the same position on different devices.
Thank you.

Comment: It is kind of reasonable that they will scroll to different positions, as not every phone's dimensions are the same. You want to find the Position of each TextView on every device instead of having a default Position to scroll to.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Do you suggest anything to start with?

Comment: Depends on how you are displaying your data. Assuming you have all your text in a ScrollView, you may want to create a RecyclerView and assign the Texts an Index in the RecyclerView List. Then you can scroll to that element in the recyclerview instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the position of a widget, for example you can add a widget to any part you want and make it invisible and then get the coordinates of that widget.

```
scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0,layout_parent.getTop());
    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0,textView.getTop()-100);
        }
    });
```